# появляющиеся пробелы в коде

Tags: html, css

Постоянно появляются дополнительные пробелы перед закрывающими ковычками. Как это исправить?

[image: постоянно появляются дополнительные пробелы перед закрывающими ковычками]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ParkHotel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css">
    <link type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" rel="icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com " crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap " rel="stylesheet ">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a href="#about-us">О нас</a>
            <a href="#entertainment">Развлечения</a>
            <a href="#apartments">Апартаменты</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <section class="park-hotel">
            <h1>Парк-отель</h1>
            <p class="parkhotel-text">Место где вы сможете забыть о городе и воссоединиться с природой</p>
            <a class="booking" href="#booking">Забронировать</a>
        </section>

        <section class="about-us" id="about-us">
            <img src="img/about-us.png" alt="рыбалка">
            <h2>О нас</h2>
            <p class="text">Наш отель расположен на снежном озере и окружён сосновым лесом. В озере можно купаться, плавать на лодке и рыбачить. На территории отеля есть много развлечений,живописных мест, где вы хорошо проведёте время.</p>
        </section>

        <section class="entertainment" id="entertainment">
            <h2>Развлечения</h2>
            <p class="text">На территории парка множество семейных развлечений на любой вкус.</p>
            <article class="entertainment-type">
                <h3>Баня</h3>
                <p>В нашем Парк-отеле вы сможете посетить настоящую Русскую баню, отдохнуть в специальной комнате, исккпаться в бассейне или озере.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="entertainment-type">
                <h3>Рыбалка</h3>
                <p>На Онежском озере вы сможете насладиться рыбалкой в окружении леса круглый год. Мы обеспечим вас всем необходимым снаряжением.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="entertainment-type">
                <h3>Спорт</h3>
                <p>В парке есть несколько спортивных площадок для детей и взрослых. Здесь вы можете арендовать велосипеды, лодку и многое другое.</p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section class="apartments" id="apartments">
            <h2>Наши аппартаменты</h2>
            <p class="text">Для создания интерьеров мы используем только экологичные материалы.</p>
            <article class="apartments-type">
                <h3>Отель</h3>
                <img src=" img/hotel.png " alt="номер в гостинице ">
                <p>10 двойных номеров и 5 номеров на троих с видом на озеро и лес. Завтрак, обед и ужин, а также ежедневная уборка номеров включены в стоимость.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="apartments-type">
                <h3>Коттедж</h3>
                <img src="img/cottage.png" alt="номер в коттедже">
                <p>5 шестиместных коттеджей с террасой, сауной местом для мангала и видом на озеро. Вы можете готовить на собственной кухне или заказывать еду из ресторана.</p>
            </article>
            <article class="apartments-type">
                <h3>Танхаус</h3>
                <img src=" img/townhouse.png " alt="номер в танхаусе ">
                <p>5 четырехместных аппартаментов с индивидуальной террасой и видом на озеро. Вы можете готовить на собственной кухне или заказывать еду из ресторана.</p>
            </article>
        </section>

        <section class="booking-form " id="booking ">
            <form>
                <h2>Забронируйте апартаменты</h2>
                <p class="text ">Напишите, в какие дни вы хотите к нам приехать и запланируйте отдых в Парк-отеле</p>
                <label class="input-type " for="usereEmail ">E-mail</label>
                <input class="form-type " tupe="email " name="email " id="usereEmail " placeholder="Ваш e-mail ">
                <lable class="input-type " for="userName ">Имя</lable>
                <input class="form-type " type="text " name="name " id="userName " placeholder="Ваше полное имя ">
                <p class="book-apartment ">Выберите тип апартаментов</p>
                <input type="radio " name="park-hotel " value="hotel " checked>
                <label class="apartments-class " for="hotel ">Отель</label>
                <input type="radio " name="park-hotel " value="cottage ">
                <label class="apartments-class " for="cottage ">Коттедж</label>
                <input type="radio " name="park-hotel " value="townhouse ">
                <label class="apartments-class " for="townhouse ">Танхаус</label>
                <input class="submit " type="submit " value="Забронировать апартаменты ">
            </form>
        </section>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <nav class="footer-menu ">
            <h3 class="footer-title ">Парк-отель</h3>
            <a href="#about-us ">о нас</a>
            <a href="#entertainment ">развлечения</a>
            <a href="#apartments ">аппартаменты</a>
        </nav>
    </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ну вы наверное генерируете html и поэтому получается так? не? но нужны бОльшие подробности. Как получается такой html, где он пишется (какая IDE) и т.д. В какой момент это появляется - когда набираете код или когда уже смотрите в браузере или ещё какой? Текущей информации ооооооооооочень недостаточно

Comment: нужен исходный код

Comment: пишу в VSC, на начальном этапе изучения верстки и вижу что не при написании кода появляется, а уже в последствии

Comment: Тот код, который вы предоставили - это тот, который вы пишите, или тот, что из браузера? Если первое - то вы сами добавляете каким-то образом пробел... как вы пишите - мы не знаем

Comment: код тот что я пишу

Comment: а как вы это делаете? получается, что это вы сами криво пишите...

Comment: Либо пробелы добавляешь сам, либо ни добавляются автоматически каким-нибудь форматтером. Также возможно, что дело в автодополнении при наборе